# scale of the y axis on ggplot for geom_line is bunched up

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, finance, r-corrplot

I am making an R markdown file using hedgefund data for an assignment for a financial econometrics class. My assignment is due on Tuesday, but I am having a few problems with how my figures are being rendered in the pdf_document.

````
```{r Q4}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
hedgefunds.long <- hedgefunds.long %>% group_by(Strategy) %>% mutate(RET = (log(NAV)- lag(log(NAV))) * 100)

ggplot(hedgefunds.long) + geom_line(aes(x = date, y = RET)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=6)) + facet_wrap(~ Strategy, ncol = 2)
````

[image: view of the squished plots for bunched up y axes for above code chunk]

Another issue I am having is that bits are cut off when the pdf document is knitted. I was wondering if there was a way to make sure that the legend in the picture below is not cut off at the top and bottom.

[watch the labels on the axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBF3z.jpg)

edit: (changed corrplot a bit, still haven't figure out resizing)

```
corrplot(hedgefundcormatrix, method = "color",addgrid.col = "gray50", tl.cex = 0.8,tl.offset = 0.5, tl.col = "black")
```

head on each dataset,

```
    > head(hedgefunds, 10)
# A tibble: 10 × 15
         date `Hedge Fund Index` `Convertible Arbitrage` `Dedicated Short Bias`
       <date>              <dbl>                   <dbl>                  <dbl>
1  1993-12-31             100.00                  100.00                 100.00
2  1994-01-31             101.14                  100.36                  98.40
3  1994-02-28              97.00                  100.51                 100.37
4  1994-03-31              93.54                   99.54                 107.59
5  1994-04-30              91.91                   97.03                 108.97
6  1994-05-31              93.96                   96.04                 111.42
7  1994-06-30              93.20                   96.24                 118.49
8  1994-07-31              93.53                   96.37                 117.09
9  1994-08-31              96.12                   96.33                 110.46
10 1994-09-30              96.76                   95.18                 112.20
# ... with 11 more variables: `Emerging Markets` <dbl>, `Equity Market
#   Neutral` <dbl>, `Event Driven` <dbl>, `Event Driven Distressed` <dbl>, `Event
#   Driven Multi-Strategy` <dbl>, `Event Driven Risk Arbitrage` <dbl>, `Fixed
#   Income Arbitrage` <dbl>, `Global Macro` <dbl>, `Long/Short Equity` <dbl>,
#   `Managed Futures` <dbl>, `Multi-Strategy` <dbl>



 head(hedgefunds.long, 10)
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: Strategy [1]

         date         Strategy    NAV        RET
       <date>            <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1  1993-12-31 Hedge Fund Index 100.00         NA
2  1994-01-31 Hedge Fund Index 101.14  1.1335510
3  1994-02-28 Hedge Fund Index  97.00 -4.1794717
4  1994-03-31 Hedge Fund Index  93.54 -3.6321826
5  1994-04-30 Hedge Fund Index  91.91 -1.7579315
6  1994-05-31 Hedge Fund Index  93.96  2.2059322
7  1994-06-30 Hedge Fund Index  93.20 -0.8121438
8  1994-07-31 Hedge Fund Index  93.53  0.3534519
9  1994-08-31 Hedge Fund Index  96.12  2.7315170
10 1994-09-30 Hedge Fund Index  96.76  0.6636275

library(tidyr)
hedgefunds.long <- tidyr::gather(hedgefunds, Strategy, NAV, -date)
```

Will try this and see if it works...will edit post if it does. 
[R - change size of axis labels for corrplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359619/r-change-size-of-axis-labels-for-corrplot)

Comment: SO is not a homework service. Please show a reproducible example, and some effort in solving your own problem.

Comment: I wrote this code, and am just started taking this class. I tried using scale_y_continuous. discrete, then tried using the package scales because I saw that might be a possible solution, but that is not working either. I figured out how to deal with na elements in the matrices to make sure the corrplot shows the proper pairwise correlations and also made sure to check that the correlations that were being found were correct by doing one pair manually. I just started getting into this class and figured out how to do the other 5 pages  for this assignment. These were the only few problems left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a reproducible data to check but it looks to me like the figure size is too small and forcing your figures to bunch up.

Play around with your figure window size, specifically the height in Q4, also consider `ncol > 2` in `facet_wrap(~ Strategy, ncol = 2)`; and both width and height for Q8.

fig.width and fig.height can be added ```{r fig.width=x, fig.height=y}

`{r Q4, fig.width=7, fig.height=10}
    # plot()`

If figure size does not fix it, you could set your margins

```
# ggplot margins 
gg + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(t,r,b,l), "cm")) # replace t,r,b,l with appropriate values
# plot margins
par(mar=c(b,l,t,r)) # replace b,l,t,r with appropriate values
plot()
```

Comment: will try this quickly and get back to you. Thanks for your insight. edited the code

Comment: made variables for the page width and length in setup code chunk, tried writing    >```{r Q4 fig.width = paperwidth, fig.height=paperlength}  .... but get an error in knitting...hmmm...

Comment: you are missing comma between Q4 and fig.width ```{r Q4, fig.width=7, fig.height=10}

Comment: for corrplot you can also add tl.cex parameter to decrease the font size, default is 1 `corrplot(..., tl.cex=0.5)`

Comment: yup it all worked out. didn't realize I could specify size in the beginning. figured out changing the labels and putting a gray grid on top. Thanks so much.

Comment: corrplot(hedgefundcormatrix, method = "color",addgrid.col = "gray50", tl.cex = 0.8,tl.offset = 0.5, tl.col = "black")